# Обработка потока/перехват данных

Tags: java, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Хочу добиться интерактивного взаимодействия с командной строкой. Для этого использовал найденный в интернете класс SyncPipe. Необходимо "достать" данные с потока(в виде строки), чтоб потом проверить на "вхождение" подстроки в строку. 
К примеру я разобрал команду ping, и хочу перехватить строку с адресом 192.168.0.1 и после чего вывести "Hello, world"

```
import java.io.*;

public class Interception {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String[] command = {"cmd"};

        ProcessBuilder grep = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        grep.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process w = grep.start();

        new Thread(new SyncPipe(w.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
        new Thread(new SyncPipe(w.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
        PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(w.getOutputStream());

        stdin.println("ping 192.168.0.1");
        stdin.flush();

        if (w.getOutputStream().toString().contains("192.168.0.1")) {

            System.out.println("Hello, World");

        }

        if (w.getInputStream().toString().contains("192.168.0.1")) {

            System.out.println("Hello, World");

        }

    }
}

class SyncPipe implements Runnable {
    public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
        istrm_ = istrm;
        ostrm_ = ostrm;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            System.out.println(buffer.length);

            for (int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
                ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final OutputStream ostrm_;
    private final InputStream istrm_;
}
```

Comment: а зачем вы используете thread? вы можете просто читать данные обрабатывать их и вы водить.

Comment: Mikhail, Thread позволяет в режиме реального времени видеть,  что выводится в командную строку.  а как вы предлагаете, можно поподробнее?